# Connecting to VMware's network from host network

Tags: networking, macos, ubuntu, vmware-fusion

I am using Ubuntu on my VMWare Fusion 7 installed on MacBook Pro Retina. I connected to internet connection via USB to lan adapter on ubuntu. Now I want to access this internet connection on OSX(host machine).

ifconfig on VM shows eth0 (i think host-only virtual adapter connecting to host) and eth1 (USB to lan)

ifconfig on OSX shows vmnet1 and vmnet8 related to VM, with some inet address ranges.

How can I now connect OSX to ubuntu's network?

Answer (score 0):

Add a bridge connection to your guest S.O, should provide you a connection to the internet and LAN resources.

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html